# Bash jq, how to read a json file where field names are like numbers?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I can't access the values ​​in the json file.
Can be a bug for labels like numerics? Or I wrong to use jq? Can you help me?
Below json sample
Sorry for my English, txs

```
{
    "datasets":{
        "0":
            {
                "0": { "0":11, "1":11,"2":10 },
                "1": { "0":73, "1":77, "2":87 },
                ....,
                ....,
                "n":{ "0":1027, "1":1025, "2":1020 }
            },
        "1":
            {
                "0": { "0":8, "1":7, "2":12 },
                "1": { "0":69, "1":75, "2":77 },
                ....,
                ....,
                "n":{ "0":1026, "1":1026, "2":1025 }
            },
        ....,
        ....,

        "99": 
            {
                "0": { "0":9, "1":9, "2":10 },
                "1": { "0":77, "1":76, "2":75 },
                ....,
                ....,
                "n":{ "0":1010, "1":1011, "2":1011 }
            },
    },
    "other_label":{
        .....
    }
}
```

I used jq command following manual but unsuccessfully. If I run:
jq .datasets
command is executed without problem. But if I add ."0" or .0 then results in:
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

Comment: `.datasets."0"` should work just fine.

Comment: If you get rid of all the `...`s and otherwise provide actual JSON that you can reproduce your problem with and we could copy/paste to test with then we could help you.

Comment: @pmf unfortunately .datasets."0" it does not work;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, it's a shell quoting issue. Given this input file:

```
{
    "datasets":{
        "0":
            {
                "0": { "0":11, "1":11,"2":10 },
                "1": { "0":73, "1":77, "2":87 },
                "n":{ "0":1027, "1":1025, "2":1020 }
            },
        "1":
            {
                "0": { "0":8, "1":7, "2":12 },
                "1": { "0":69, "1":75, "2":77 },
                "n":{ "0":1026, "1":1026, "2":1025 }
            },
        "99": 
            {
                "0": { "0":9, "1":9, "2":10 },
                "1": { "0":77, "1":76, "2":75 },
                "n":{ "0":1010, "1":1011, "2":1011 }
            }
    },
    "other_label":{
    }
}
```

I can run this command line:

```
jq '.datasets."0"' data.json
```

And get this output:

```
{
  "0": {
    "0": 11,
    "1": 11,
    "2": 10
  },
  "1": {
    "0": 73,
    "1": 77,
    "2": 87
  },
  "n": {
    "0": 1027,
    "1": 1025,
    "2": 1020
  }
}
```

You need the outer quotes so that the quotes around `"0"` are actually seen by `jq`.